# Replacing selected characters in a PHP string

Tags: php, substr

I have a variable :

```
$var = '+44123456789';
```

And I want to replace the 3 characters, that are 3 characters from the end with X's so :

```
$var = '+44123XXX789';
```

I know I could use :

```
$var = substr($var, 0, 6) . 'XXX' . substr($var, -3);
```

But the issue I have is that `$var` can be of varying lengths.

How would I set up substr to make this work in the same way but on a variable of any length? (P.S. `$var` will always be at least 8 chars long.)

Comment: Mathematics 101: use strlen() to get the length, then subtract 6

Comment: Or even `$var = substr($var, 0, -6) . 'XXX' . substr($var, -3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$var = '+44123123789';

echo substr($var, 0, strlen($var) - 6) . 'XXX' . substr($var, -3);//+44123XXX789

$var = '+44123123789111';

echo substr($var, 0, strlen($var) - 6) . 'XXX' . substr($var, -3);//+44123123XXX111
```

see [demo here](https://eval.in/475909)

Comment: This was perfect and very easy to understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

calculate string length and then process the substr as given below

```
 $var = '+44123456789';
$len=strlen($var);
if($len>10){
$len=$len-6;
$var = substr($var, 0, $len) . 'XXX' . substr($var, -3);}
elseif($len==10){
$var = substr($var, 0, 6) . 'XXX' . substr($var, -3);
}
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access chars in a string by index:

```
$var = '+44123456789';
$c = strlen($var)-6;
$var[$c++] = $var[$c++] = $var[$c++] = 'X';
echo $var;
```